# How to invoke method from other file in C#?

Tags: c#

In my program, I need Memory Scanner. I've used this one: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/716227/Csharp-How-to-Scan-a-Process-Memory
I've created a new C# file named MemoryScanner.cs and copied the code there.

How to run it from here:

```
private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //here I would like to invoke the MemoryScanner
    }
```

Thanks in advance for every help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently (from looking at the code of the link your provided), the entry point of the program is the static method `Main` in class `Program` in namespace `MemoryScanner`. Call this method to start the code.

Some points should be noted:

- The implementation is left as an exercise. *(If you really don't know how to call a static method in C#, please start with a good, basic C# tutorial.)*
- Currently, the code analyzes a process called `notepad`, outputs the result to `dump.txt` and waits for Console entry before returning. If you want to use that as part of your program, you will need to change these things. (Hint: Remove the Console parts and pass the values, which are currently hard-coded, as method parameters.)

In a nutshell: If you want to use the code, you won't get around reading and (at least partly) understanding it.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a using statement at the top of your page.

```
using MemoryScanner;
```

Comment: I've added "using MemoryScanner;", but it says that MemoryScannerRun(); doesn't exist in current context. I've changed the method name from main to MemoryScannerRun to not have two mains in program.

Comment: Did you try Program.MemoryScannerRun()

Comment: I did not, but it doesn't work either. I don't know if there is a problem with namespaces. MemoryScanner has MemoryScanner namespace and the rest of the code has namespace Pokemonsy.